# Enable textbox in usercontrol from form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I want to enable or disable textboxes when they load on my winform. The textboxes, however, are in a usercontrol.

Can I make methods for enabling/disabling these textboxes like so?

```
public void EnableTextbox(TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.Enabled = true;
    }

public void DisableTextbox(TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.Enabled = false;
    }
```

and them from my form:

```
EnableTextbox(///Name of textbox)
```

Or do I have to name them inside the method?

Comment: The form shouldn't know that much about the UserControl's inner workings, so it should be just `public void EnableTextbox()` and inside the method, just set the TextBox control to false.

Comment: Indeed.  And it should be a property of type *bool* with a name like "PasswordEntryEnabled", whatever it functionally does.  You create a class to *encapsulate* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a FindControl method inside your UserControl, like this:

```
 UserControl myControl = new UserControl();//You must not create a new instace, you need to poitn at yours.
        TextBox referencedTextBox =  (TextBox)myControl.FindControl("myTextBoxId");
        //referencedTextBox.WhateverYouWant
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this from your root  form and it will access every control within itself and its children. All you need to do is complete the logic to determine if a TextBox should be disabled or not. I recommend calling this in the constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`.

```
    private void ProcessControl(Control cntrl)
    {
        if (cntrl == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (cntrl is TextBox)
        {
            if (true) //condition to determine if the textbox is enabled
            {
                cntrl.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cntrl.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else if (cntrl.HasChildren)
        {
            foreach (Control item in cntrl.Controls )
            {
                ProcessControl(item);
            }
        }
    }
```